# Start and configure a WildFly server and deploy the app using wildfly-maven-plugin in 1 maven run

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I want to have a way to run maven so that it will:

- start a WildFly server instance in standalone mode (`wildfly:run`)
- deploy the hsqldb driver
- add a datasource
- deploy the application

The problem is that:

- `wildfly:run` blocks so no other maven goals can be executed
- the server instance must be running before it can be configured or an app can be deployed (daaa)

A possible work around that comes to my mind is:

- `wildfly:start`
- configure the server and deploy the app
- block until the user presses CTRL-C, is there a maven plugin that does that?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. mvn wildfly:start does not block. Were you able to come up with a solution?

Comment: @fansonly No, I came up with some workaround that I do not remember now, but not an ultimate solution. If you have time I encourage you to deliver the new feature (https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin) that James has mentioned in his answer - a configuration property to not register the shutdown hook and leave the process running.

Comment: I will look in to doing that if the project manager gives me the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the parameter **beforeDeployment** of the run `goal` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30356389/390177)):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <beforeDeployment>
            <commands>
                <command>data-source add --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS --name=testDB --connection-url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 --driver-name=h2 --user-name=sa --password=sa</command>
            </commands>
        </beforeDeployment>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you need additional libraries for your database driver you can do something like that ([source](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/configuring-a-datasource-with-postgresql-and-jboss-wildfly)):

```
module add --name=org.postgres --resources=/tmp/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgres",driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `wildfly:start` goal will not block and it has a shutdown hook to destroy the process once maven exits. It may be worth adding a configuration property to not register the shutdown hook and leave the process running.. ..but I'm getting off topic.

Since maven runs goals based on a lifecycle phase you could invoke the `start` and `deploy` goal in a phase that runs before the `package` phase. The `run` goal requires the `package` phase so anything before that should work.

Comment: I have tried that, but when `wildfly:run` is executed after `wildfly:start` it tries to start a new WildFly instance using the same ports, what of course fails.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what your use case is or why `wildfly:start` followed by `wildfly:deploy` is not enough.

Are you doing manual or automatic testing?

For integration testing, if `wildfly-maven-plugin` does not suit your needs, have a look at [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) and its Maven and WildFly support.

Comment: because `wilfdly:start` does not block, so once `wildfly:start` and `wildfly:deploy` is completed the started WildFly instance will be shut down.